# Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged or similar custom event in base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, aop, inotifypropertychanged, castle

Is there a way to do this:

I need to develop the easiest way to support registering to property changes of some class. Apart from manual way of adding INotifyProperyChanged support, is there a way to do it like this:

```
class Base ... // all notification logic here

class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SomeNumber { get; set; }
    // etc....
}
```

so that I can do Child.PropertyChanged += some_handler and be notified only on Child property changes.
This isn't for NHibernate, or anything else, it is for manual use in entire project. I have looked into some examples of doing this with Castle Dynamic Proxy (like [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/07/nhibernate-amp-inotifypropertychanged.aspx)), but I don't understand how to exploit it :(

Sure would like to explore there frameworks and AOP in general, I just don't have enuogh time right now ...

Thank you in advance for any comments...

Comment: Ok ... I am getting somewhere ... To begin with mentioned link using Castle DP, you must cast created object to INotifyPropertyChanged. To simplify, you could create something like: public static void Register<T>(T toRegister, PropertyChangedEventHandler handler) { ((INotifyPropertyChanged)toRegister).PropertyChanged += handler; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proxies or AOP really are your only options for doing this automagically, so you will need to either find the time to investigate or do it the [good old-fashioned way](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-viewmodel.html).